# Android DrawerLayout - openDrawer with Gravity.Start creates a lint error "Must be one or more of..."

Tags: android, lint, drawerlayout, gravity

I have created a `DrawerLayout` and also have an `ImageView` (a 'hamburger') that opens it when clicked.
My problem is that when using the following code, a lint error is shown in AndroidStudio: `Must be one or more of: Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT...`, there is no `Gravity.START` in there.

```
ImageView openDrawerImageView = findViewById(R.id.open_drawer_image_icon);
openDrawerImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I looked for a while for an answer but did not find one. I decided to leave it for later since this is only a lint error and the app actually does work with `Gravity.START`.
Later I needed to close the drawer in some scenario so I used: `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(START)` then I used the autocomplete, and got the answer: *GravityCompat*

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: looks like a lint bug (the message should refer GravityCompat instead of Gravity)